# Is there a work around for 'LIKE' in BeamSQL?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, beam-sql

We have an Apache Beam 2.4.0 pipeline that runs BeamSql queries. In BeamSql the SQL statement 'LIKE' throws an exception 'LIKE is not implemented yet'. Is there a work around for 'LIKE' in BeamSql? We need to be able to perform wildcard queries on strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to define a UDF that implements the logic.

I have filed [BEAM-4385](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4385) to track implementation of `LIKE`.

A more complete set of operators will be supported when [BEAM-2281](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2281) is addressed.

Comment: to add to Kenn's answer, link to the guide about UDFs: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/user-defined-functions/